# Dynamically set onclick behaviour of html button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML button:

```
<button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
```

I want to set the `onclick` behaviour - link to a page depending on the URL parameters for this button. On searching, I found that it is only possible through Javascript, through something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
  function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
      if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1];
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() { return "location.href=\'index.html?param=" + GetURLParameter('param') + "\'"; };
</script>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. My button doesn't do anything when clicked. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have seen some questions which work by creating the button dynamically using JS and then set its onclick behaviour. However, I am interested in knowing how one can modify the onclick behaviour of a button which has been created using HTML through JS.

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser's console ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ No :|

Comment: You don't need to return the link but to change `window.location` value to make te redirection.

Comment: ^ Didn't quite understand this. Do you mean to say something like `document.getElementById('reset').onclick = 'window.location="index.html?param=' + GetURLParameter('param') + '"';` ?

Comment: See my answer, it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `"` mark after `location.href=` and you do not need a `return` statement.

```
document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
  location.href="\'index.html?param=" + GetURLParameter('param') + "\'";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, your event function won't do anything. The return value is just controlling the native event (ie. you can block a link by returning false). If you want to redirect the user, you probably want something like that (not tested):

```
document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
    location.href='index.html?param=' + GetURLParameter('param');
    return false; // This will block other possibly actions
};
```

```js
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
  location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37567793";
  return false;
};
```

```html
<button id="test">
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: I updated with an example, but stackoverflow blocks it. Nevertheless, it reacts on the click and try to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The function called on the `onclick` event does not need to return the URL but to define the `window.location`.

Also, you are binding the `onclick` before the document is fully loaded, so when it tries to bind the event, the button does not exist, so nothing happens when you click on it.

Here is a working example (with jQuery):

```
<button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
<script>
    function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reset").click(function(){
            window.location = "index.html?param=" + GetURLParameter('param');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The same example in native JS:

```
<button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
<script>
    function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
            window.location = "index.html?param=" + GetURLParameter('param');
        };
    };
</script>
```